# EntityManager Configuration to Fetch Data Oracle DB - SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, hibernate-entitymanager

New to Spring boot. What i am trying is to connect my Application to the DB and fetch me the info via an ENtityManager. When i run my App, i am facing some exception. Exception i have attached in the every end.

These are my classes.

**Application.Properties** file

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
#management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *
#FPL    FPLADMIN@//localhost:1521/ORCLPDB
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCLPDB
spring.datasource.username = FPLADMIN
spring.datasource.password = oracle1
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tester</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-jar</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**FplUser.java**  (Entity)

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FPL_USER")
public class FplUser {

    public FplUser(String userName, String userPassword, char emailVerificationStatus) {
        this.emailVerificationStatus = emailVerificationStatus;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FPL_USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 100, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "FPL_USER_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "JPA_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "USERPASSWORD")
    private String userPassword;

    @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION")
    private char emailVerificationStatus;
```

**FplUserRepo.java**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class FplUserRepo {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    
    public long inserNewUser(String userName, String userPassword, char emailVerificationStatus) {
        FplUser fplUser = new FplUser(userName,userPassword,emailVerificationStatus);
        em.persist(fplUser);
        return fplUser.getId();
    }
}
```

**DemoApp.java**

```
package com.tester.demojar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.tester.demojar.repository.FplUserRepo;
import com.tester.demojar.repository.TempRepo;
import com.tester.demojar.repository.TempRepoSecondApproach;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJarApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private FplUserRepo fplUserRepo;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoJarApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("welcome to La Liga FPL");
        
        long newId = fplUserRepo.inserNewUser("Vendetta","bogus", 'N');
        System.out.println("New User Id "+newId);
        
    }
}
```

> **ORACLE DATABASE**

**Table**

[image]

**Sequence**

[image]

**Trigger**

[image]

*Exception*

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.5.0-SNAPSHOT)

2021-05-24 15:24:00.332  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] com.tester.demojar.DemoJarApplication    : Starting DemoJarApplication using Java 11.0.11 on ARVO11 with PID 15332 (C:\Users\TheWorkGuy\Downloads\demo-jar\demo-jar\target\classes started by TheWorkGuy in C:\Users\TheWorkGuy\Downloads\demo-jar\demo-jar)
2021-05-24 15:24:00.334  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] com.tester.demojar.DemoJarApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-05-24 15:24:00.393  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\TheWorkGuy\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\21.1.0.0\ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/TheWorkGuy/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/21.1.0.0/oraclepki.jar
2021-05-24 15:24:00.393  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-05-24 15:24:00.394  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-05-24 15:24:01.383  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-24 15:24:01.442  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 48 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-05-24 15:24:01.872  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'management.metrics-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.873  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.data.RepositoryMetricsAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.874  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.876  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'management.metrics.export.simple-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.878  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'simpleConfig' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimplePropertiesConfigAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.881  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.882  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'micrometerClock' of type [io.micrometer.core.instrument.Clock$1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.897  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'simpleMeterRegistry' of type [io.micrometer.core.instrument.simple.SimpleMeterRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.901  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'repositoryTagsProvider' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.data.DefaultRepositoryTagsProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:01.902  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'metricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener' of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.data.MetricsRepositoryMethodInvocationListener] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-05-24 15:24:02.439  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-24 15:24:02.454  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-24 15:24:02.454  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-05-24 15:24:02.555  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-24 15:24:02.555  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2161 ms
2021-05-24 15:24:02.982  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-24 15:24:03.488  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-05-24 15:24:03.552  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-05-24 15:24:03.628  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-05-24 15:24:03.852  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-05-24 15:24:03.997  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
2021-05-24 15:24:04.391 ERROR 15332 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser]
2021-05-24 15:24:04.392  WARN 15332 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser]
2021-05-24 15:24:04.393  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-05-24 15:24:04.407  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-05-24 15:24:04.408  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-05-24 15:24:04.421  INFO 15332 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-24 15:24:04.443 ERROR 15332 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.tester.demojar.DemoJarApplication.main(DemoJarApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.lambda$new$1(SessionFactoryImpl.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [FPL_USER_SEQ] sequence is set to [100] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: OK i see that increment in DB is 1.
But in Code. these is the line
@SequenceGenerator(name = "FPL_USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 100, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "FPL_USER_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "JPA_ID")
    private long id;

don't understand when you say increment is set to 50.

Comment: This: `allocationSize = 100` should be like this: `allocationSize = 1`

Comment: SIlly me, Bittersweet feeling. Banging my head for past 3 hours seeing all videos and stuff.
this HELPED. I am able to do proceed without the exception. THANKS A LOT !! :) @SternK